# Virtual function invoking segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, virtual-functions, vtable

I am getting a segmentation fault whenever I am trying to access a virtual function. The code is basically like this:

```
class Super {
  public:
    Super() { cout << "Ctor Super" << endl; }
    virtual void test() = 0;
  };

class Sub : public Super {
  public:
    Sub() { cout << "Ctor Sub" << endl; }
    void test() { cout << "Test in Sub" << endl; }
  };

void main()
 {
   Super* s = new Sub;
   s->test(); // Segmentation fault So I tried the one below

   Sub* s1 = new Sub;
   s1->test(); //Still segmentation fault

   Sub s2;
   s2.test(); // Works fine BUT

   Super *s3 = &s2;
   s3->test(); // segmentation fault and EVEN

   Sub *s4 = &s2;
   s4->test(); //segmentation fault
 }
```

I have tried almost everything I know about virtual functions and it does not work. It's actually a part of a bigger program so it might have some problem there but as soon as I remove the virtual function or stop making it virtual it works. Any Ideas?

Also is there any tool or way to examine the vtable?

Comment: The code builds and runs fine here.

Comment: yups it should, but its not on my machine. I am running it on a LYnxOS powerPC machine. Can you think of any situation where it should not run.

Answer (score 0):

Class Sub does not inherit from class Super, so they aren't related in any way as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

Can this code compile at all?

- All your methods are private.
- There is no inheritance between Sub and Super.
- The constructor are wrongly named.
- The main() function does not return int.

Fixing all these results in a code that compiles and runs without a segfault.

Comment: Yes this code compiles and executes.. that is why I am getting a seg fault. Its a c++ code, I think you are confusing it with some other language (java probably....). Anyway help if you find someting... cheers.

Comment: The code did not look the way it looks now when I (and Joe) answered.  The first three points have been fixed.  It is still invalid C++ because main() should return int (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c), but that would not justify a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see what could cause the problem except a compiler bug. Can you give the exact compiler version?

In the meantime, I would try the following:

- add a dummy `int` member to the classes. It might be that a zero-sized class causes wrong code generation.
- declare `Sub::test()` as virtual, too. Again, might be the compiler misbehaving here.

Also, what kind of segmentation fault are you getting? Is it precisely `SIGSEGV` or is it another signal? Could you give a debugger backtrace and local assembly dump?